# Can't submit data in textarea

Tags: php, jquery

This is my code, I'm trying to get data inside #download div and submit it to other file test2.php
Don't worry it is just table inside #download

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<form action="test2.php" method="post">
<textarea style="" id="file" name="file"></textarea>
<input type="submit">
</form>
<script>

$(document).ready(function(e) {
   var html=$('#download').html(); 
   $('#file').val(html);
});

</script>

<div id="download">
<div id="content">

<table border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="7" id="info"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="7" id="info_space"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top" class="sirinaStupca"><!-- 1. STUPAC -->
  </tr>
</table>

</div>
</div>
```

Other file just needs to echo it, for testing purpose, but it throws me an error: Error 404
Unable to resolve the request "test2.php". When I put normal text or css() instead of table it is working. I can't figure it out why.

```
if(isset($_POST["file"]))
{
    echo $_POST["file"];
}
```

Comment: `.val(value)` doesn't do what you think it does... you might want to read the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/val/

Comment: Hint: You probably want to use `.text(textString)` http://api.jquery.com/text/

Comment: Everything is working fine, your code is ok... You just can't see outputed HTML, because browser renders it as HTML, not plain text, but check it by - view source. ;) Your 'echo' on test2.php page really echoes submitted html...

Comment: on the other server it says Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /test2.php on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: Hm... something related to server settings (security settings i would say, maybe) - try this: echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['file']) in your test2.php file...

Comment: Nothing. I will have to contact my server provider :(

Comment: @FosAvance, yes, definitely -> for some reason, you can't send plain html tags via $_POST. I have tested on my host - all works fine...

Comment: They sad mod_security doesn't block that from being executed